# Error when creating table on Excel 2016 for Mac

Tags: office-js

I am executing the following on Excel 2016 for Mac (15.36.170702):

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx: Excel.RequestContext) {
    var tblAddress = "Sheet1!A1:P12";
    var masterTable : Excel.Table = ctx.workbook.tables.add(tblAddress, true);
    return ctx.sync();
}
```

Getting following error:

```json
{
    "code": "GeneralException",
    "message": "GeneralException",
    "errorLocation": "TableCollection.add"
}
```

This same code runs properly on Excel for Windows and Excel Online.

Comment: Same code works in office 365 and Windows Excel.

Comment: Have you tried catching the error rather than leaving it uncaught? Adding `.catch(function(error) { console.log("Error: " + error);})` may give you more insight into what is going on.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know the version/build number of Excel you're seeing this on.

Comment: Excel Version: 15.36(170702). The JSON error is from catch only.  {
    "code": "GeneralException",
    "message": "GeneralException",
    "errorLocation": "TableCollection.add"
}

Comment: Try changing the tblAddress to just the top row instead of the whole expected range of the table:  "Sheet1!A1:P1". See if that makes any difference.

Comment: I've tested this code on 15.39 and didn't run into an issue. I suspect there is something else occurring prior to this.